# Efficient conditional selection with masks in very large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selection, mask

I have a dataframe with some 2 million rows like this:

```
                    dt   num
0  2019-05-12 10:17:00   135
1  2018-01-16 21:32:00     5
2  2017-11-30 22:29:00   135
3  2017-10-05 16:59:00    19
4  2017-08-07 05:26:00     5
5  2017-06-12 17:47:00    18
```

For each and all of the different values in column 'num' I need to find the corresponding minimum value of column 'dt'.

I am doing it with a list comprehension with a mask followed by an operator:

```
[(num_i, df[df.num == num_i].dt.min()) for num_i in set(df.num)]
```

It works, but it is taking really a lot ot time.
Any other way to solve it that is less time consuming?

---

Ooops ... thanks to all! (@It_is_Chris, @papke, @paul-brennan).
I was thinking in making a time comparison, but the solution provided (groupby) solves it in seconds against close to one hour...

Comment: group by the num column and get the min date: `df.groupby(df['num'])['dt'].min()`

Comment: Thanks, @It_is_Chris: it has reduced the time from abt one hour to few seconds!

Answer (score 0):

@It_is_Chris was exactly right, and if you have more cores available, parallel the job with the groupby apply trick.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def applyParallel(dfGrouped, func):
    with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
        ret_list = p.map(func, [group for name, group in dfGrouped])
    return pandas.concat(ret_list)
```

so pass in the df.groupby(df['num']) as dfGrouped and then have the function defined as you would like it.

Comment: Thanks, @PaulBrennan: I do not need the extra performance of multiprocessing, but I take note.

Answer (score 0):

```
mins = df.groupby("num")["dt"].min()
print(mins)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Please, if possible, avoid using images for code/data. It is always better to post it as text and format as code, even in this case the output is not crucial. Also always try to add a description to your code.

Comment: @Ruli I’m just curious. Why not use images ?

Comment: In this case it is not so problematic, showing output is not crucial. However, in many cases it decrease readability, images can't be found through search engines, link can break by time, data cannot be copied, etc. There is explanation for questions [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3157428), of course it applies to answers as well. That's why I commented to make you aware that it is not a good practice, your post appeared in low quality posts review queue.

Comment: @Ruli I understand. Thanks. I read the guidelines. I never post images of code. I occasionally append images of the output, if that output is a data frame, to assist the original asker in visualizing it . It is not necessary for it to be searchable and it doesn’t matter if the image link breaks at some point. I’ll definitely take your suggestion of adding a description to the code.